# Exporting PLY - No difference between moving object and moving its origin?

Tags: export, edit-mode, vertices, origin, point-clouds

I create models in Blender, export them as point clouds and use them in another project.

Today I wanted to test the following use case and I am surprised that the exported ply file looks differently than I thought it would. Maybe this behavior is based on the nature of the PLY format or maybe it is a behavior of Blender itself. I hope someone can help me out with this.

**My initial situation:**

1. I have a model that I simply move one meter on the X axis in `Object Mode`. The origin of the model remains in the center of the model by default.
2. I have a model that I simply move one meter on the X axis in `Edit Mode`. I leave the origin in the center of the scene.

**Expecting:**

After exporting both models as a .ply file I expect them to have different vertices/coordinates because they have different origins.
This means, for example, that the model with the origin at the center of the model itself should have negative vertices on the X axis. The model with the origin at the center of the scene, on the other hand, has no negative vertices on the X axis (Of course, with the condition that the model is not larger than one meter in radius).

**Results:**
Both .ply files have the same vertices/coordinates.

**My Questions:**
What is my mistake?
Is there an origin of the object origin?
Is there a global and local origin and I mistakenly export with the global Origin?
How can I export the models to meet my expectations?